# Ошибка при работе со словарем в словаре

Tags: python, словари, словарь

Мне нужно перебрать ключи в словаре, который находится в другом словаре

```
dict1 = {
'first_dict' : {'first' : 1, 'second' : 2},
'second_dict' : {'first' : 1, 'second' : 2}
}
for k in dict1.keys():
    for kk in k.keys():
        print(kk)
```

Но выдается ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Я понимаю, что `k` не является словарем, а строкой. Как сделать `k` словарем?

Comment: `for k in dict1.values(): for kk in k.keys(): print(kk)` В первом случае надо итерировать по значениям, а не ключам

Comment: А как мне после этого изменить конкретное значение?

Answer (score 1):

Можно перебрать вот так:

```
dict1 = {
    'first_dict': {'first': 1, 'second': 2},
    'second_dict': {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
}
for k in dict1.keys():
    for kk in dict1[k].keys():
        print(dict1[k][kk])
```

Вывод

```
1
2
1
2
```